# Adding WifiManager to METAR map

Tags: arduino, esp8266, wifimanager

I am creating a METAR map for a friend for Christmas and was looking at creating an easier way for him to change his WiFi password on it without manipulating the code. Doing some research I have found this link https://www.circuitschools.com/change-wifi-credentials-of-esp8266-without-uploading-code-again/ but having trouble where to put it and what I need to change in the original code. https://github.com/WKHarmon/led-sectional/blob/master/led-sectional.ino is the link to the code I was using to start. I was able to get it working great but I just want to make it a bit easier to set up.

Below is what I currently have running on the board.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define FASTLED_ESP8266_RAW_PIN_ORDER

#define NUM_AIRPORTS 50 // This is really the number of LEDs
#define WIND_THRESHOLD 30 // Maximum windspeed for green, otherwise the LED turns yellow
#define LOOP_INTERVAL 5000 // ms - interval between brightness updates and lightning strikes
#define DO_LIGHTNING true // Lightning uses more power, but is cool.
#define DO_WINDS true // color LEDs for high winds
#define REQUEST_INTERVAL 300000 // How often we update. In practice LOOP_INTERVAL is added. In ms (5 min is 300000)

#define USE_LIGHT_SENSOR false // Set USE_LIGHT_SENSOR to true if you're using any light sensor.
// Set LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561 to true if you're using a TSL2561 digital light sensor.
// Kits shipped after March 1, 2019 have a digital light sensor. Setting this to false assumes an analog light sensor.
#define LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561 false

const char ssid[] = "LAB200-2G"; // your network SSID (name)
const char pass[] = "P3nnylane"; // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
// Define the array of leds
CRGB leds[NUM_AIRPORTS];
#define LED_PIN    14 // Kits shipped after March 1, 2019 should use 14. Earlier kits us 5.
#define LED_TYPE    WS2811
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB
#define BRIGHTNESS 30 // 20-30 recommended. If using a light sensor, this is the initial brightness on boot.

/* This section only applies if you have an ambient light sensor connected */
#if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
/* The sketch will automatically scale the light between MIN_BRIGHTNESS and
MAX_BRIGHTNESS on the ambient light values between MIN_LIGHT and MAX_LIGHT
Set MIN_BRIGHTNESS and MAX_BRIGHTNESS to the same value to achieve a simple on/off effect. */
#define MIN_BRIGHTNESS 30 // Recommend values above 4 as colors don't show well below that
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 30 // Recommend values between 20 and 30

// Light values are a raw reading for analog and lux for digital
#define MIN_LIGHT 16 // Recommended default is 16 for analog and 2 for lux
#define MAX_LIGHT 30 // Recommended default is 30 to 40 for analog and 20 for lux

#if LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_TSL2561_U.h>
#include <Wire.h>
Adafruit_TSL2561_Unified tsl = Adafruit_TSL2561_Unified(TSL2561_ADDR_FLOAT, 12345);
#else
#define LIGHTSENSORPIN A0 // A0 is the only valid pin for an analog light sensor
#endif

#endif
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

std::vector<unsigned short int> lightningLeds;
std::vector<String> airports({
  "NULL", // 1
  "KMSP",// 2
  "KGFK", // 3
  "KPHL", // 4
  "KCEC", // 5
  "NULL", // 6
  "NULL", // 7
  "KMRY", // 8
  "KSNS", // 9
  "KCVH", // 10
  "KWVI", // 11
  "KE16", // 12
  "KRHV", // 13
  "KSJC", // 14
  "KNUQ", // 15
  "KPAO", // 16
  "KSQL", // 17
  "KHAF", // 18
  "KSFO", // 19
  "KOAK", // 20
  "KHWD", // 21
  "KLVK", // 22
  "KC83", // 23
  "NULL", // 24
  "KCCR", // 25
  "NULL", // 26
  "KDVO", // 27
  "KO69", // 28
  "KSTS", // 29
  "NULL", // 30
  "KAPC", // 31
  "KSUU", // 32
  "KVCB", // 33
  "KEDU", // 34
  "KSMF", // 35
  "KSAC", // 36
  "KMHR", // 37
  "KMCC", // 38
  "KLHM", // 39
  "KMYV", // 40
  "KBAB", // 41
  "NULL", // 42
  "KOVE", // 43
  "NULL", // 44
  "KCIC", // 45
  "NULL", // 46
  "KRBL", // 47
  "NULL", // 48
  "NULL", // 49
  "KGFK", // 50
});

#define DEBUG false

#define READ_TIMEOUT 15 // Cancel query if no data received (seconds)
#define WIFI_TIMEOUT 60 // in seconds
#define RETRY_TIMEOUT 15000 // in ms

#define SERVER "www.aviationweather.gov"
#define BASE_URI "/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecentForEachStation=true&stationString="

boolean ledStatus = true; // used so leds only indicate connection status on first boot, or after failure
int loops = -1;

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(74880);
  //pinMode(D1, OUTPUT); //Declare Pin mode
  //while (!Serial) {
  //    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
  //}

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // give us control of the onboard LED
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  #if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
  #if LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561
  Wire.begin(D2, D1);
  if(!tsl.begin()) {
    /* There was a problem detecting the TSL2561 ... check your connections */
    Serial.println("Ooops, no TSL2561 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
  } else {
    tsl.enableAutoRange(true);
    tsl.setIntegrationTime(TSL2561_INTEGRATIONTIME_13MS);
  }
  #else
  pinMode(LIGHTSENSORPIN, INPUT);
  #endif
  #endif

  // Initialize LEDs
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, LED_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
}

#if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
void adjustBrightness() {
  unsigned char brightness;
  float reading;

  #if LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561
  sensors_event_t event;
  tsl.getEvent(&event);
  reading = event.light;
  #else
  reading = analogRead(LIGHTSENSORPIN);
  #endif

  Serial.print("Light reading: ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" raw, ");

  if (reading <= MIN_LIGHT) brightness = 0;
  else if (reading >= MAX_LIGHT) brightness = MAX_BRIGHTNESS;
  else {
    // Percentage in lux range * brightness range + min brightness
    float brightness_percent = (reading - MIN_LIGHT) / (MAX_LIGHT - MIN_LIGHT);
    brightness = brightness_percent * (MAX_BRIGHTNESS - MIN_BRIGHTNESS) + MIN_BRIGHTNESS;
  }

  Serial.print(brightness);
  Serial.println(" brightness");
  FastLED.setBrightness(brightness);
  FastLED.show();
}
#endif

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // on if we're awake

  #if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
  adjustBrightness();
  #endif

  int c;
  loops++;
  Serial.print("Loop: ");
  Serial.println(loops);
  unsigned int loopThreshold = 1;
  if (DO_LIGHTNING || USE_LIGHT_SENSOR) loopThreshold = REQUEST_INTERVAL / LOOP_INTERVAL;

  // Connect to WiFi. We always want a wifi connection for the ESP8266
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    if (ledStatus) fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Orange); // indicate status with LEDs, but only on first run or error
    FastLED.show();
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.hostname("LED Sectional " + WiFi.macAddress());
    //wifi_set_sleep_type(LIGHT_SLEEP_T); // use light sleep mode for all delays
    Serial.print("WiFi connecting..");
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // Wait up to 1 minute for connection...
    for (c = 0; (c < WIFI_TIMEOUT) && (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED); c++) {
      Serial.write('.');
      delay(1000);
    }
    if (c >= WIFI_TIMEOUT) { // If it didn't connect within WIFI_TIMEOUT
      Serial.println("Failed. Will retry...");
      fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Orange);
      FastLED.show();
      ledStatus = true;
      return;
    }
    Serial.println("OK!");
    if (ledStatus) fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Purple); // indicate status with LEDs
    FastLED.show();
    ledStatus = false;
  }

  // Do some lightning
  if (DO_LIGHTNING && lightningLeds.size() > 0) {
    std::vector<CRGB> lightning(lightningLeds.size());
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < lightningLeds.size(); ++i) {
      unsigned short int currentLed = lightningLeds[i];
      lightning[i] = leds[currentLed]; // temporarily store original color
      leds[currentLed] = CRGB::White; // set to white briefly
      Serial.print("Lightning on LED: ");
      Serial.println(currentLed);
    }
    delay(25); // extra delay seems necessary with light sensor
    FastLED.show();
    delay(25);
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < lightningLeds.size(); ++i) {
      unsigned short int currentLed = lightningLeds[i];
      leds[currentLed] = lightning[i]; // restore original color
    }
    FastLED.show();
  }

  if (loops >= loopThreshold || loops == 0) {
    loops = 0;
    if (DEBUG) {
      fill_gradient_RGB(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Red, CRGB::Blue); // Just let us know we're running
      FastLED.show();
    }

    Serial.println("Getting METARs ...");
    if (getMetars()) {
      Serial.println("Refreshing LEDs.");
      FastLED.show();
      if ((DO_LIGHTNING && lightningLeds.size() > 0) || USE_LIGHT_SENSOR) {
        Serial.println("There is lightning or we're using a light sensor, so no long sleep.");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(LOOP_INTERVAL); // pause during the interval
      } else {
        Serial.print("No lightning; Going into sleep for: ");
        Serial.println(REQUEST_INTERVAL);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(REQUEST_INTERVAL);
      }
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(RETRY_TIMEOUT); // try again if unsuccessful
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(LOOP_INTERVAL); // pause during the interval
  }
}

bool getMetars(){
  lightningLeds.clear(); // clear out existing lightning LEDs since they're global
  fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Black); // Set everything to black just in case there is no report
  uint32_t t;
  char c;
  boolean readingAirport = false;
  boolean readingCondition = false;
  boolean readingWind = false;
  boolean readingGusts = false;
  boolean readingWxstring = false;

  std::vector<unsigned short int> led;
  String currentAirport = "";
  String currentCondition = "";
  String currentLine = "";
  String currentWind = "";
  String currentGusts = "";
  String currentWxstring = "";
  String airportString = "";
  bool firstAirport = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_AIRPORTS; i++) {
    if (airports[i] != "NULL" && airports[i] != "VFR" && airports[i] != "MVFR" && airports[i] != "WVFR" && airports[i] != "IFR" && airports[i] != "LIFR") {
      if (firstAirport) {
        firstAirport = false;
        airportString = airports[i];
      } else airportString = airportString + "," + airports[i];
    }
  }

  BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure();
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (!client.connect(SERVER, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
    client.stop();
    return false;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connected ...");
    Serial.print("GET ");
    Serial.print(BASE_URI);
    Serial.print(airportString);
    Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    Serial.print("Host: ");
    Serial.println(SERVER);
    Serial.println("User-Agent: LED Map Client");
    Serial.println("Connection: close");
    Serial.println();
    // Make a HTTP request, and print it to console:
    client.print("GET ");
    client.print(BASE_URI);
    client.print(airportString);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(SERVER);
    client.println("User-Agent: LED Sectional Client");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.flush();
    t = millis(); // start time
    FastLED.clear();

    Serial.print("Getting data");

    while (!client.connected()) {
      if ((millis() - t) >= (READ_TIMEOUT * 1000)) {
        Serial.println("---Timeout---");
        client.stop();
        return false;
      }
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(1000);
    }

    Serial.println();

    while (client.connected()) {
      if ((c = client.read()) >= 0) {
        yield(); // Otherwise the WiFi stack can crash
        currentLine += c;
        if (c == '\n') currentLine = "";
        if (currentLine.endsWith("<station_id>")) { // start paying attention
          if (!led.empty()) { // we assume we are recording results at each change in airport
            for (vector<unsigned short int>::iterator it = led.begin(); it != led.end(); ++it) {
              doColor(currentAirport, *it, currentWind.toInt(), currentGusts.toInt(), currentCondition, currentWxstring);
            }
            led.clear();
          }
          currentAirport = ""; // Reset everything when the airport changes
          readingAirport = true;
          currentCondition = "";
          currentWind = "";
          currentGusts = "";
          currentWxstring = "";
        } else if (readingAirport) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentAirport += c;
          } else {
            readingAirport = false;
            for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < NUM_AIRPORTS; i++) {
              if (airports[i] == currentAirport) {
                led.push_back(i);
              }
            }
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<wind_speed_kt>")) {
          readingWind = true;
        } else if (readingWind) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentWind += c;
          } else {
            readingWind = false;
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<wind_gust_kt>")) {
          readingGusts = true;
        } else if (readingGusts) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentGusts += c;
          } else {
            readingGusts = false;
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<flight_category>")) {
          readingCondition = true;
        } else if (readingCondition) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentCondition += c;
          } else {
            readingCondition = false;
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<wx_string>")) {
          readingWxstring = true;
        } else if (readingWxstring) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentWxstring += c;
          } else {
            readingWxstring = false;
          }
        }
        t = millis(); // Reset timeout clock
      } else if ((millis() - t) >= (READ_TIMEOUT * 1000)) {
        Serial.println("---Timeout---");
        fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Cyan); // indicate status with LEDs
        FastLED.show();
        ledStatus = true;
        client.stop();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  // need to doColor this for the last airport
  for (vector<unsigned short int>::iterator it = led.begin(); it != led.end(); ++it) {
    doColor(currentAirport, *it, currentWind.toInt(), currentGusts.toInt(), currentCondition, currentWxstring);
  }
  led.clear();

  // Do the key LEDs now if they exist
  for (int i = 0; i < (NUM_AIRPORTS); i++) {
    // Use this opportunity to set colors for LEDs in our key then build the request string
    if (airports[i] == "VFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Green;
    else if (airports[i] == "WVFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Yellow;
    else if (airports[i] == "MVFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Blue;
    else if (airports[i] == "IFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
    else if (airports[i] == "LIFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Magenta;
  }

  client.stop();
  return true;
}

void doColor(String identifier, unsigned short int led, int wind, int gusts, String condition, String wxstring) {
  CRGB color;
  Serial.print(identifier);
  Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.print(condition);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(wind);
  Serial.print("G");
  Serial.print(gusts);
  Serial.print("kts LED ");
  Serial.print(led);
  Serial.print(" WX: ");
  Serial.println(wxstring);
  if (wxstring.indexOf("TS") != -1) {
    Serial.println("... found lightning!");
    lightningLeds.push_back(led);
  }
  if (condition == "LIFR" || identifier == "LIFR") color = CRGB::Magenta;
  else if (condition == "IFR") color = CRGB::Red;
  else if (condition == "MVFR") color = CRGB::Blue;
  else if (condition == "VFR") {
    if ((wind > WIND_THRESHOLD || gusts > WIND_THRESHOLD) && DO_WINDS) {
      color = CRGB::Yellow;
    } else {
      color = CRGB::Green;
    }
  } else color = CRGB::Black;

  leds[led] = color;
}
```

Here is the website that I used as guidance https://www.rickgouin.com/make-your-own-metar-weather-map/

I explained my process in the paragraph above

Comment: did you see the Basic.ino example? https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.ino

Comment: Yes. I guess just having trouble understanding it. Could I essentially just put that code in my setup function and rewrite in the loop? is there anything in the current code that I will have to take out?

Comment: and you will have to replace `WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);` in `loop()` with just `WiFi.begin();` which will use the remembered ssid and password to reconnect if the WiFi gets disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Working code

Thanks for the help everyone!

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <vector>
#include <WiFiManager.h> // https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager


using namespace std;

#define FASTLED_ESP8266_RAW_PIN_ORDER

#define NUM_AIRPORTS 50 // This is really the number of LEDs
#define WIND_THRESHOLD 30 // Maximum windspeed for green, otherwise the LED turns yellow
#define LOOP_INTERVAL 5000 // ms - interval between brightness updates and lightning strikes
#define DO_LIGHTNING true // Lightning uses more power, but is cool.
#define DO_WINDS true // color LEDs for high winds
#define REQUEST_INTERVAL 300000 // How often we update. In practice LOOP_INTERVAL is added. In ms (5 min is 300000)

#define USE_LIGHT_SENSOR false // Set USE_LIGHT_SENSOR to true if you're using any light sensor.
// Set LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561 to true if you're using a TSL2561 digital light sensor.
// Kits shipped after March 1, 2019 have a digital light sensor. Setting this to false assumes an analog light sensor.
#define LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561 false

// WIFI Management for ESP8266
WiFiManager wm;
#define WIFI_TIMEOUT 120 // in seconds
// Parameters for ESP8266 access point
#define ESP_WIFI_SSID "METAR Map"
#define ESP_WIFI_PASSWORD "1234"

// Define the array of leds
CRGB leds[NUM_AIRPORTS];
#define LED_PIN    14 // Kits shipped after March 1, 2019 should use 14. Earlier kits us 5.
#define LED_TYPE    WS2811
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB
#define BRIGHTNESS 30 // 20-30 recommended. If using a light sensor, this is the initial brightness on boot.

/* This section only applies if you have an ambient light sensor connected */
#if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
/* The sketch will automatically scale the light between MIN_BRIGHTNESS and
MAX_BRIGHTNESS on the ambient light values between MIN_LIGHT and MAX_LIGHT
Set MIN_BRIGHTNESS and MAX_BRIGHTNESS to the same value to achieve a simple on/off effect. */
#define MIN_BRIGHTNESS 30 // Recommend values above 4 as colors don't show well below that
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 30 // Recommend values between 20 and 30

// Light values are a raw reading for analog and lux for digital
#define MIN_LIGHT 16 // Recommended default is 16 for analog and 2 for lux
#define MAX_LIGHT 30 // Recommended default is 30 to 40 for analog and 20 for lux

#if LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_TSL2561_U.h>
#include <Wire.h>
Adafruit_TSL2561_Unified tsl = Adafruit_TSL2561_Unified(TSL2561_ADDR_FLOAT, 12345);
#else
#define LIGHTSENSORPIN A0 // A0 is the only valid pin for an analog light sensor
#endif

#endif
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

std::vector<unsigned short int> lightningLeds;
std::vector<String> airports({
  "NULL", // 1
  "KMSP",// 2
  "KGFK", // 3
  "KPHL", // 4
  "KDVL", // 5
  "KGFK", // 6
  "KGFK", // 7
  "KMRY", // 8
  "KSNS", // 9
  "KCVH", // 10
  "KWVI", // 11
  "KE16", // 12
  "KRHV", // 13
  "KSJC", // 14
  "KNUQ", // 15
  "KPAO", // 16
  "KSQL", // 17
  "KHAF", // 18
  "KSFO", // 19
  "KOAK", // 20
  "KHWD", // 21
  "KLVK", // 22
  "KC83", // 23
  "KGFK", // 24
  "KCCR", // 25
  "KGFK", // 26
  "KDVO", // 27
  "KO69", // 28
  "KSTS", // 29
  "KGFK", // 30
  "KAPC", // 31
  "KSUU", // 32
  "KVCB", // 33
  "KEDU", // 34
  "KSMF", // 35
  "KSAC", // 36
  "KMHR", // 37
  "KMCC", // 38
  "KLHM", // 39
  "KMYV", // 40
  "KBAB", // 41
  "KGFK", // 42
  "KOVE", // 43
  "KGFK", // 44
  "KCIC", // 45
  "KGFK", // 46
  "KRBL", // 47
  "KGFK", // 48
  "NGFK", // 49
  "KGFK", // 50
});

#define DEBUG false

#define READ_TIMEOUT 15 // Cancel query if no data received (seconds)
#define RETRY_TIMEOUT 15000 // in ms

#define SERVER "www.aviationweather.gov"
#define BASE_URI "/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecentForEachStation=true&stationString="

boolean ledStatus = true; // used so leds only indicate connection status on first boot, or after failure
int loops = -1;

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // give us control of the onboard LED
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  #if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
  #if LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561
  Wire.begin(D2, D1);
  if(!tsl.begin()) {
    /* There was a problem detecting the TSL2561 ... check your connections */
    Serial.println("Ooops, no TSL2561 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
  } else {
    tsl.enableAutoRange(true);
    tsl.setIntegrationTime(TSL2561_INTEGRATIONTIME_13MS);
  }
  #else
  pinMode(LIGHTSENSORPIN, INPUT);
  #endif
  #endif

  // Initialize LEDs
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, LED_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
}

#if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
void adjustBrightness() {
  unsigned char brightness;
  float reading;

  #if LIGHT_SENSOR_TSL2561
  sensors_event_t event;
  tsl.getEvent(&event);
  reading = event.light;
  #else
  reading = analogRead(LIGHTSENSORPIN);
  #endif

  Serial.print("Light reading: ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.print(" raw, ");

  if (reading <= MIN_LIGHT) brightness = 0;
  else if (reading >= MAX_LIGHT) brightness = MAX_BRIGHTNESS;
  else {
    // Percentage in lux range * brightness range + min brightness
    float brightness_percent = (reading - MIN_LIGHT) / (MAX_LIGHT - MIN_LIGHT);
    brightness = brightness_percent * (MAX_BRIGHTNESS - MIN_BRIGHTNESS) + MIN_BRIGHTNESS;
  }

  Serial.print(brightness);
  Serial.println(" brightness");
  FastLED.setBrightness(brightness);
  FastLED.show();
}
#endif

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // on if we're awake

  #if USE_LIGHT_SENSOR
  adjustBrightness();
  #endif

  int c;
  loops++;
  Serial.print("Loop: ");
  Serial.println(loops);
  unsigned int loopThreshold = 1;
  if (DO_LIGHTNING || USE_LIGHT_SENSOR) loopThreshold = REQUEST_INTERVAL / LOOP_INTERVAL;

  // Connect to WiFi. We always want a wifi connection for the ESP8266  
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    if (ledStatus) fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Orange); // indicate status with LEDs, but only on first run or error
    FastLED.show();
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    wm.setConfigPortalTimeout(WIFI_TIMEOUT);
  }
      if(wm.autoConnect(ESP_WIFI_SSID,ESP_WIFI_PASSWORD)){
          Serial.println("Connected to local network");
          if (ledStatus) fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Purple); // indicate status with LEDs
          FastLED.show();
          ledStatus = false;
      } 
      else {
         Serial.println("Failed to connect to local network or hit timeout");
          fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Orange);
          FastLED.show();
          ledStatus = true;
          return;
      }          
  

  // Do some lightning
  if (DO_LIGHTNING && lightningLeds.size() > 0) {
    std::vector<CRGB> lightning(lightningLeds.size());
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < lightningLeds.size(); ++i) {
      unsigned short int currentLed = lightningLeds[i];
      lightning[i] = leds[currentLed]; // temporarily store original color
      leds[currentLed] = CRGB::White; // set to white briefly
      Serial.print("Lightning on LED: ");
      Serial.println(currentLed);
    }
    delay(25); // extra delay seems necessary with light sensor
    FastLED.show();
    delay(25);
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < lightningLeds.size(); ++i) {
      unsigned short int currentLed = lightningLeds[i];
      leds[currentLed] = lightning[i]; // restore original color
    }
    FastLED.show();
  }

  if (loops >= loopThreshold || loops == 0) {
    loops = 0;
    if (DEBUG) {
      fill_gradient_RGB(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Red, CRGB::Blue); // Just let us know we're running
      FastLED.show();
    }

    Serial.println("Getting METARs ...");
    if (getMetars()) {
      Serial.println("Refreshing LEDs.");
      FastLED.show();
      if ((DO_LIGHTNING && lightningLeds.size() > 0) || USE_LIGHT_SENSOR) {
        Serial.println("There is lightning or we're using a light sensor, so no long sleep.");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(LOOP_INTERVAL); // pause during the interval
      } else {
        Serial.print("No lightning; Going into sleep for: ");
        Serial.println(REQUEST_INTERVAL);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(REQUEST_INTERVAL);
      }
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(RETRY_TIMEOUT); // try again if unsuccessful
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(LOOP_INTERVAL); // pause during the interval
  }
}

bool getMetars(){
  lightningLeds.clear(); // clear out existing lightning LEDs since they're global
  fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Black); // Set everything to black just in case there is no report
  uint32_t t;
  char c;
  boolean readingAirport = false;
  boolean readingCondition = false;
  boolean readingWind = false;
  boolean readingGusts = false;
  boolean readingWxstring = false;

  std::vector<unsigned short int> led;
  String currentAirport = "";
  String currentCondition = "";
  String currentLine = "";
  String currentWind = "";
  String currentGusts = "";
  String currentWxstring = "";
  String airportString = "";
  bool firstAirport = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_AIRPORTS; i++) {
    if (airports[i] != "NULL" && airports[i] != "VFR" && airports[i] != "MVFR" && airports[i] != "WVFR" && airports[i] != "IFR" && airports[i] != "LIFR") {
      if (firstAirport) {
        firstAirport = false;
        airportString = airports[i];
      } else airportString = airportString + "," + airports[i];
    }
  }

  BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure();
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (!client.connect(SERVER, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
    client.stop();
    return false;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connected ...");
    Serial.print("GET ");
    Serial.print(BASE_URI);
    Serial.print(airportString);
    Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    Serial.print("Host: ");
    Serial.println(SERVER);
    Serial.println("User-Agent: LED Map Client");
    Serial.println("Connection: close");
    Serial.println();
    // Make a HTTP request, and print it to console:
    client.print("GET ");
    client.print(BASE_URI);
    client.print(airportString);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(SERVER);
    client.println("User-Agent: LED Sectional Client");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.flush();
    t = millis(); // start time
    FastLED.clear();

    Serial.print("Getting data");

    while (!client.connected()) {
      if ((millis() - t) >= (READ_TIMEOUT * 1000)) {
        Serial.println("---Timeout---");
        client.stop();
        return false;
      }
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(1000);
    }

    Serial.println();

    while (client.connected()) {
      if ((c = client.read()) >= 0) {
        yield(); // Otherwise the WiFi stack can crash
        currentLine += c;
        if (c == '\n') currentLine = "";
        if (currentLine.endsWith("<station_id>")) { // start paying attention
          if (!led.empty()) { // we assume we are recording results at each change in airport
            for (vector<unsigned short int>::iterator it = led.begin(); it != led.end(); ++it) {
              doColor(currentAirport, *it, currentWind.toInt(), currentGusts.toInt(), currentCondition, currentWxstring);
            }
            led.clear();
          }
          currentAirport = ""; // Reset everything when the airport changes
          readingAirport = true;
          currentCondition = "";
          currentWind = "";
          currentGusts = "";
          currentWxstring = "";
        } else if (readingAirport) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentAirport += c;
          } else {
            readingAirport = false;
            for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < NUM_AIRPORTS; i++) {
              if (airports[i] == currentAirport) {
                led.push_back(i);
              }
            }
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<wind_speed_kt>")) {
          readingWind = true;
        } else if (readingWind) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentWind += c;
          } else {
            readingWind = false;
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<wind_gust_kt>")) {
          readingGusts = true;
        } else if (readingGusts) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentGusts += c;
          } else {
            readingGusts = false;
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<flight_category>")) {
          readingCondition = true;
        } else if (readingCondition) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentCondition += c;
          } else {
            readingCondition = false;
          }
        } else if (currentLine.endsWith("<wx_string>")) {
          readingWxstring = true;
        } else if (readingWxstring) {
          if (!currentLine.endsWith("<")) {
            currentWxstring += c;
          } else {
            readingWxstring = false;
          }
        }
        t = millis(); // Reset timeout clock
      } else if ((millis() - t) >= (READ_TIMEOUT * 1000)) {
        Serial.println("---Timeout---");
        fill_solid(leds, NUM_AIRPORTS, CRGB::Cyan); // indicate status with LEDs
        FastLED.show();
        ledStatus = true;
        client.stop();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  // need to doColor this for the last airport
  for (vector<unsigned short int>::iterator it = led.begin(); it != led.end(); ++it) {
    doColor(currentAirport, *it, currentWind.toInt(), currentGusts.toInt(), currentCondition, currentWxstring);
  }
  led.clear();

  // Do the key LEDs now if they exist
  for (int i = 0; i < (NUM_AIRPORTS); i++) {
    // Use this opportunity to set colors for LEDs in our key then build the request string
    if (airports[i] == "VFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Green;
    else if (airports[i] == "WVFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Yellow;
    else if (airports[i] == "MVFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Blue;
    else if (airports[i] == "IFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
    else if (airports[i] == "LIFR") leds[i] = CRGB::Magenta;
  }

  client.stop();
  return true;
}

void doColor(String identifier, unsigned short int led, int wind, int gusts, String condition, String wxstring) {
  CRGB color;
  Serial.print(identifier);
  Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.print(condition);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(wind);
  Serial.print("G");
  Serial.print(gusts);
  Serial.print("kts LED ");
  Serial.print(led);
  Serial.print(" WX: ");
  Serial.println(wxstring);
  if (wxstring.indexOf("TS") != -1) {
    Serial.println("... found lightning!");
    lightningLeds.push_back(led);
  }
  if (condition == "LIFR" || identifier == "LIFR") color = CRGB::Magenta;
  else if (condition == "IFR") color = CRGB::Red;
  else if (condition == "MVFR") color = CRGB::Blue;
  else if (condition == "VFR") {
    if ((wind > WIND_THRESHOLD || gusts > WIND_THRESHOLD) && DO_WINDS) {
      color = CRGB::Yellow;
    } else {
      color = CRGB::Green;
    }
  } else color = CRGB::Black;

  leds[led] = color;
}
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.